# Valgrind reporting too many mallocs

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind, free

Consider this code:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char *string = NULL;
    string = malloc(sizeof(char) * 30);
    free(string);
    return 0;
}
```

I malloc a char pointer then I free it after. Now consider the valgrind output:

```
==58317== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==58317== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==58317== Using Valgrind-3.11.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==58317== Command: ./a.out
==58317== 
==58317== 
==58317== HEAP SUMMARY:
==58317==     in use at exit: 34,941 bytes in 424 blocks
==58317==   total heap usage: 505 allocs, 81 frees, 41,099 bytes allocated
==58317== 
==58317== LEAK SUMMARY:
==58317==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==58317==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==58317==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==58317==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==58317==         suppressed: 34,941 bytes in 424 blocks
==58317== 
==58317== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==58317== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

How is it possible to have that many mallocs and frees?

Edit: This is what I get when I run with `valgrind --leak-check=yes --gen-suppressions=all ./a.out`, I am trying to make a supp file.

```
==60943== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==60943== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==60943== Using Valgrind-3.11.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==60943== Command: ./a.out
==60943== 
==60943== 
==60943== HEAP SUMMARY:
==60943==     in use at exit: 34,941 bytes in 424 blocks
==60943==   total heap usage: 505 allocs, 81 frees, 41,099 bytes allocated
==60943== 
==60943== LEAK SUMMARY:
==60943==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==60943==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==60943==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==60943==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==60943==         suppressed: 34,941 bytes in 424 blocks
==60943== 
==60943== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==60943== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 15 from 15)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this here - are you sure that your a.out is actually built from the above code ?

Comment: With your code I got `==14910==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 30 bytes allocated` What are you headers ? How do you compil the binary ?

Comment: `gcc -g main.c` I am sure my a.out is built from the above code.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: I also get `total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 30 bytes allocated` - maybe there is something odd about your version of gcc and/or valgrind ?

Comment: As indicated further in the output, those "leaked" blocks are suppressed - if you're using the default suppression file, those would be allocations done by system libraries and the like. You can use the `-v` option to get more details on what was suppressed.

Comment: Ping @RhysKidd  - he is one of the valgrind developers working on OS X support.

Comment: I feel silly, how do I do that?

Comment: See if you can duplicate [this result](http://kalapun.com/posts/checking-c-code-with-valgrind-on-yosemite/).  If you can't, I would suspect that your computer may have a virus.

Comment: @Edward I did not install from subversion, and I don't get the same leaks as on that site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those blocks were allocated (and some of them freed as well) by a system library that was linked into your executable.

Valgrind has a default [suppression](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress) file that suppresses leaks in system libraries, which is what you can see further in the output :

```
==58317==         suppressed: 34,941 bytes in 424 blocks
```

If you want more details on what exactly was suppressed, you can use the `-v` option.

Comment: @user3711622 : yes - they are usually false positives, and only sometimes real leaks in system libraries that are difficult to fix. But I've never seen them amount to much. In other words : if they are suppressed by default, they should be safe to ignore.

Comment: How can I "hide" these from my output so I can see memory leaks that I caused?

Comment: @user3711622 : that's what the suppression file is for - it suppresses these known leaks, so you can focus on the real ones (by looking at the other lines in the leak summary eg.).

Comment: @user3711622 : try removing the `free(string);` line from your code - the valgrind output should then report a leak (clearly distinguishable from the suppressed leaks).

Comment: It suppresses known leaks in specific libraries, those you cannot really fix. From there, you can test for leaks in your actual program.

Comment: I am trying to make a supp file and I am starting to get a little bit frustrated. Please see my edit.

Comment: @user3711622 : you don't need to create one. The default suppression file already suppresses those system leaks (as evidenced by the original valgrind output you showed).

Comment: Is there a way I can suppress the 504 `allocs` and 80 `frees`?

Comment: @user3711622 : As I said, the leaks among those blocks are already suppressed. If you mean you don't want to display them as part of the total heap usage, then afaik that's not possible. There shouldn't be a reason to either.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker then how am I supposed to know how many `allocs` and `frees` I was responsible for?

Comment: @user3711622 : you can't in general with valgrind's leak checker. But that's not what that's for anyway. What you want, is a memory profiler, like [massif](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) eg. (or any other that strikes your fancy). Since that's no longer related to your original question though, any further questions about that would belong in a new question.

Comment: Also note that since you're on OS X you might want to look at Apple's own memory debugging tools that come with Xcode.